# "No such module" 3rd Party framework import issues everytime project is opened

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks

I am getting the

> No such module 'Google Mobile Ads'

Warning everytime I open my project. And every single time I have to drag in the framework and link it up again. It is still in the project folder, but for some reason Xcode cannot find the framework every time.

It looks like this:

[image: Error]

How do I fix it. I have tried many guides online linking the framework in `Build Phases` or in `Build Settings`, but all of them tell me different things.

TL;DR:
**What is the proper way to import a 3rd party framework into a project?**

In this case GoogleMobileAds.

Comment: Maybe add an Xcode version you are using. Looks like existing problem for Xcode 7.3.1

Answer (score 0):

The way  is just create a directory
 for the framework at the same directory level as your
 application project. I prefer to have the code for the framework outside of the code for my  projects for cleanliness of version control, but that's a matter of personal preference.
The instructions for the setup of the framework assume that you 
already have a set location for your GPUImage code in your filesystem (~/Downloads is probably not that place). Pulling in the .xcodeproj merely links to that location. You'll also need to know that location to set where the framework header search path is.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cocoapods!

If you want to show AdMob ads in your app, you first need to connect your app to Firebase and get a `GoogleService-Info.plist` and put it in your project. You can learn how to do that here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start#streamlined_using_cocoapods

Just create a new project in the console and add an app to the project. Then you're ready to install the SDK.

Now, download cocoapods using the Terminal

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Enter your password and Cocoapods will start downloading.

Then navigate to your project using `cd` and do this:

```
pod init
```

Go to your project directory and open the `Podfile` using Xcode. In that file, add these lines in the `target MyApp do` thingy:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
```

Then, uncomment the two lines at the top:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!
```

In terminal, do

```
pod install
```

And wait.

BOOM! now you can add the AdMob framework in the project settings. **But remember, once you used cocoapods, *NEVER* open your xcodeproj file again. You should open the .xcworkspace file with the same name.**

After you added the framework into your project, you need to Build before you can import the framework into your code.

---

> How do I install a 3rd party library?

Let's say you want to install `AFNetworking`, a popular networking library. Just add this line to your Podfile:

```
pod 'AFNetworking'
```

And run `pod install`

You basically do the same thing with every library. The only difference is the thing in the Podfile.

Comment: I did this, but for some reason Xcode still can't find GoogleMobileAds

Comment: @Hokkaido  try cleaning the project and building it

Comment: Doesn't work any way to not use Cocoapods? I've used it in the past and it just makes my projects stupidly messy!